# Is there a Java standard "both null or equal" static method?

Tags: java, null, equals

To save some typing and clarify my code, is there a standard version of the following method?

```
public static boolean bothNullOrEqual(Object x, Object y) {
  return ( x == null ? y == null : x.equals(y) );
}
```

Comment: Can someone say where such a thing is useful ?

Comment: It just allows you to skip null checks in your equals() method.

Comment: Only if you only ever use the bothNullOrEqual function... what if you use equals directly in one place?

Comment: It does seem strange that you'd want the same behaviour if two objects were equal OR were both NULL ...

Comment: If you are implementing a Collection, your .contains() method, when given "o" needs to test "if this collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))." Similarly, your .remove() method has to remove such an element.

Comment: Just my two cents. I would use:

    public static boolean bothNullOrEqual(Object x, Object y) {
      return ( x == y || ( x != null && x.equals(y) ) );
    }

IMHO, It's more readable for novice programmers.

Comment: Another use case: compare a value to see if it has changed from it's previous value during a dirty check.

Comment: You might want to update the selected answer to @Kdeveloper's Java 7 solution.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

With Java 7 you can now directly do a null safe equals:

[Objects.equals(x, y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)

(The Jakarta Commons library ObjectUtils.equals() has become obsolete with Java 7)

Comment: This method is also implemented in Googles Dependency injection-libray Guice.

Comment: Spring also implements a similar method: nullSafeEquals on ObjectUtils class

Comment: Google Guava has Objects.equals() as well.

Comment: This is only nullsafe concering x. For y it depends on the implementation   of equals of the given object. (the implementation is `return (x == y) || (x != null && x.equals(y));`)

Answer (score 23):

if by some chance you are have access to the Jakarta Commons library there is [ObjectUtils.equals()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) and lots of other useful functions.

EDIT: misread the question initially

Answer (score 8):

If you are using <1.7 but have Guava available: [`Objects.equal(x, y)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))